# AWS Route53: Private and public hosted zones under the same domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I've read through all the AWS docs I can find. And Google too has not resulted in anything.

My case here is - we have one domain "example.com", used only for public records, so far. There is one Hosted Zone set to Public. Now, I want to create a subdomain for private records to be used inside of our VPC group for our application (e.g. to point at an ElastiCache instance).

I attempted to create "private.example.com" as a Private Hosted Zone pointing at our VPC. Then created "cache.private.example.com" as a record under it. But it did not resolve.

I am curious if I can configure a subdomain of our main domain somehow?

```
example.com - Public
** app.example.com 
private.example.com - Private
** cache.private.example.com - VPC
```

OR

Can I also create a Private Hosted Zone with the same top level domain example.com? I am nervous to try that because I do not want to affect the application.

```
example.com - Public
** app.example.com
example.com - Private
** cache.example.com - VPC'
```

Comment: Why do you crested two subdomains "private.example.com" and "cache.private.example.com"

Comment: @error2007s I was attempting to use the entire private.example.com subdomain as the private hosted zone. I will only have one record in it for now but will have more in the future.

Comment: Check below answer

Comment: Define "it will not resolve."  What happens when you try?  What happens if you put a conflicting record in the public zone for (e.g. cache.private.example.com)?  If the public record resolves inside the VPC then you have a misconfiguration, which we'll need to pinpoint.

Comment: No, don't create a private example.com zone unless you are prepared to duplicate all the records from the public zone. Private masks public at the same level or below.

Answer (score 11):

**For Googlers trying to "subsetting" a public host zone, or to make a private host zone "fallback" or "extend" to public. Read on.**

Firstly, R53 is authoritative, means you have to provide exact resolution, so the common way of using different BIND views will not work. Also when host zone names overlap, the private one prevails.

Secondly, R53 will determine which host zone to use based on "specificity". So when user asks for `www.example.com`, then a host zone named `www.example.com` prevails another named `example.com`. This is something we can make use of.

Follow the procedure:

- Create a public host zone for your public DNS record (e.g. `example.com`), or just use any other public DNS record and skip this step
- Create a private host zone **for each** of your sub domain name that has a local / private mirror / cache (e.g. `www.example.com`)
- Create a default record set for each of the private host zones (leaving the "Name" field empty) and point them to local addresses
- Attach the private host zones to your selected VPC's

In this way, if your machine asks for `www.example.com`, and a private host zone matches, it will return local addresses, otherwise, it will fallback to use the public host zone.

The pitfall for this solution is that R53 charges you by number of host zones, so you will have to pay a bit more. Also this is a bit hacky. Otherwise it eliminates the complexity of creating and managing your own BIND server, syncing public records, etc.

Comment: This is accurate. But I would add that once you create, for example, a "www.example.com" private hosted zone, then anything under that will also use that private hosted zone. So trying to get to "server2.www.example.com" will result in looking up its IP in the "www.example.com" private hosted zone, not in the public zone.

Answer (score 8):

You will need to have a different domain for the private zone. Something like "example.internal" Then you could have "cache.example.internal"

cache.private.example.com will not resolve in your current setup, because it will be looking to example.com to resolve that dns. Also note it will only resolve inside the VPC.

Comment: I found this blurb which lead me to believe example 2 was possible, but was unsure it it only worked for "split-view" or could work as I laid out.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html

See the section on "Split View"

Comment: @MatthewMcCants, no.  One private hosted zone at private.example.com will coexist just fine with a public zone example.com and have exactly the desired behavior -- private records visible only internally, public records outside public.example.com visible in and out. There is no conflict nor ambiguity in this configuration.  The private masks the public at the apex of the private zone and below -- not above.